# How to share an object across all sockets using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am struggling to create an object for storing the number of clients in a room. It would look something like this: { Room0: 1, Room1: 4, Room2: 3}, and whenever a socket connection/disconnection occurs (joins or leaves a room), this object will be updated and all existing sockets can have access to it at all times.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set a variable in the global scope (outside of the onMessage or onEvent listeners). Then, in your join rooms code, you would have a part where you would add to the count of the room. It's a crude way to do it.

`var rooms = {lobby: 0, kitchen: 0}`

Inside your room joining section, lets say they joined the lobby, then you would do this inside that block:

`rooms.lobby++`

Then, any socket that wants to know the number of people in the lobby need only call:

`rooms.lobby`